# Как сделать проверку в Advanced Custom Fields, если значение поля не заполнено, то вывести значения из полей опции в повторителе

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-плагины, acf

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать проверку не пустое ли значение поля на странице, если пусто, то вывести значение из поля опции для повторителя в advanced custom fields? Т.е. я создаю костомные поля для шаблона и отдельно для опции. 
Например, есть повторитель images, вывожу его так:

```
if ( have_rows('images') ) :
    while ( have_rows('images') ): the_row();
    endwhile;
endif;
```

для опции так:

```
if ( have_rows( 'images', options) ) :
    while ( have_rows( 'images', options) ): the_row();
    endwhile;
endif;
```

Как сделать, что если значение поля присвоенное странице пустое, то взять из полей опции?

Comment: Приложите полный пример

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$images = get_field( 'images' ) ? : get_field( 'images', 'options' );
foreach( $images as $image ) {
    // и работайте как с массивом. Например: $image['src'];
}
```

Comment: То что нужно.Спасибо за помощь!;)